# How can i find most frequent element in 2d array ? you are not allowed to use anything but 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, element

int element = array[0][0];
        int count = 0;

```
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {

            int tempElement = array[row][col];
            int tempCount = 0;

                for (int x = 0;  x< array.length;x++){
                    for(int y=0; y<array[x].length;y++){

                        if(array[x][y] == tempElement){

                            tempCount++;
                        }

                        if(tempCount > count) {

                            element = tempElement;
                            count = tempCount;

                        }


                    }


                }

        }

    }

    System.out.println("The most common height in the terrain is " + element + " it occurs " + count + " times");
```

this is what I have try so far

I have given 1 million elements of a data set in 2d array and I have to find the most frequent element from that data set using java we are only allowed to use arrays

Comment: What have you tried so far, if anything?

Comment: yaa i just edit my question

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You mention infinite loop - how do you know it's infinite? It looks like you have an extremely poor complexity algorithm (of O(n^2) on the total number of elements) but not an infinite loop. Do you have to use 2D arrays or is a 1D array good too? You could copy the values to a 1D array of the right size, call `Arrays.sort` on it, and then count the longest run of the same value. That would be O(n*log n), better at least. If you can use a HashMap you can do even better. (If you have a limited number of possible values, you don't need a HashMap)

Comment: is there any way i can reduce time complexity of my algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

I would flatten the array and then sort it. Then you can run through the array counting up elements and checking your count each time the value changes.

```
int [][] arr = { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}};
int [] flatArray = Arrays.stream(arr).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sorted().toArray();
int previousValue = -1;
int findCounter = 0;
int maxFindCounter = -1;
int maxValueFound = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < flatArray.length; i++) {
  if(previousValue != flatArray[i]) {
    if(findCounter > maxFindCounter) {
      maxFindCounter = findCounter;
      maxValueFound = previousValue;
    }
    findCounter = 0;
  }
  previousValue = flatArray[i];
  findCounter ++;
}
System.out.println(maxValueFound + " : " + maxFindCounter);
```